# jquery not working on JSP when the same works fine on HTML

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, tomcat, taglib

I am working towards a datetime picker utility on JSP (primarily on Spring: Form but going back to debug on plain JSP for now to find the root cause). While the same works perfectly fine on HTML, I am unable to run it on JSP. I am running this on Tomcat 7.0. Please help me with this. Here is my code:

test.html: WORKS Fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>DateTimePicker</h3>
    <input type="text" value="2014/03/15 05:06" id="datetimepicker"/><br><br>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
    .datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03',step:10});


</script>
</html>
```

In the JSP with the same code as above the script does not work, I even tried including the .css and .js files as below, provided all the mentioned files are present in the current folder and the web.xml is provided with default servlet mapping for .css and .js files already.

```
 <%@ include file="jquery.datetimepicker.css"%>
 <%@ include file="jquery.js"%>  
 <%@ include file="jquery.datetimepicker.js"%>
```

Another date picker only feature I worked with earlier works well with Spring:Form. Here is the code which is rather complicated for execution as it used Spring tag libraries. One noticeable aspect here is that the .css and .js references are web URLs and not local files.

working JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="reminderObject">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><form:input type="text" path="date"  id="datepicker"/></td>
    <script>  $(function() {    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()});  </script>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: did you find any error on browser console? It may happened that .js files not get loaded properly.

Comment: Hi Bhushan, I am not getting any error on browser or console

Comment: As you said it is working on html but not in jsp, so it is mostly due to not getting required js files. see this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resources to check resources downloaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the rocket science we tried here, its was this `<!DOCTYPE html>` which when included in the JSP file did the trick for me. Taken by surprise yet very happy I am through now. Thank you Bhushan Kawadkar and Nirav Prajapati for your valuable involvement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Remove your includes line that you right for include js and put above 2 lines and then try

Comment: Hi Nirav, I tried it this way but it did not resolve the issue. I am able to get the context root printed (SOP) with ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}, even placed the .js files in context root as well but the script is still not working.

Comment: I have placed it in the .js files at the below places to check if it may pick from anywhere but it does not work:
`WEB-INF/pages/, 
Context Root/, 
Context Root/src/resources/, 
WEB-INF/`

Comment: i mean provide me full path for example in which folder you have your js file like. : webcontent > resourse > js > jquery.js

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/src/resources/jquery.js"></script>

try this one